# erro na instalação do pygame no vs code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pip

Ao instalar o pygame no vs code pelo console e ele me retornou o seguinte:

```
pip install pygame
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9qsem_9r/pygame/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-9qsem_9r/pygame/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-9qsem_9r/pygame/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-9qsem_9r/pygame/
    Complete output (18 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using UNIX configuration...


    Hunting dependencies...
    SDL     : found 1.2.15
    FONT    : not found
    IMAGE   : not found
    MIXER   : not found
    PNG     : found
    JPEG    : found
    SCRAP   : found
    PORTMIDI: not found
    PORTTIME: not found
    FREETYPE: found 23.1.17
    Missing dependencies
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

**Ja tentei**

1. pip install -U setuptools
2. sudo -H pip install -U setuptools

Answer (score -1):

O problema é mais provável com o python 3.8, você precisa compilá-lo ou usar uma versão mais antiga do python (<= 3.7).

Answer (score -1):

Pode ser que voce ja tenha tentado, mas tente esses procedimentos, ja tive bastante problema com isso tambem, e na maioria das vezes, eram detalhes pequenos.

Qnd tive o problema foi com o Pandas, acontecia o msm erro, comigo, funcionou quando eu resetei a Venv (apaguei e criei outra). Pois pode ser que tenha alguma biblioteca que esteja barrando.

Entao segue algumas dicas, talvez ajude:

- Reveja a versao do seu Python e seu pip esta atualizado
  Eu uso o Python 3.8.10 e instala tranquilamente.
- Tente instalar no seu PC antes, pelo cmd mesmo e depois retorne pro seu editor, ele usara os arquivos em cache.
- Veja se esta dentro da venv e se o mesmo esta ativado.
- Feche e abra novamente o editor.

Em ultimo caso

- Caso utilize o VSCode, como e um editor leve, desistale e instale novamente, e coisa rapida.
- Reeinstale dentro do VSCode o extensor do Python.

Caso nenhuma dessas alternativas nao funcionar, em ultumo caso mesmo, crie uma VM e tente por la, mas assim nao iria resolver o problema em si, mas consegue contornar para poder dar prosseguimento.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).